# Import other modules by default in Swift files

Tags: swift, xcode, compiler-optimization

I have 2 projects in a workspace. **Main Project** and **Style** project. I have some extensions in the **Style** project. When I want to use these extensions in the **main project**, I need to import the **Style** project. I need to import it into about **4000** files. Is there any way to import the **Style** file by default in every swift file?

I don't have such a problem for **UIKit** and **Foundation** frameworks. I can use them without importing.